# Multivariable Utility functions

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, utility

For a highschool economics/mathematics interdisciplinary essay I will use the Lagrange multipliers and deriving formulas that find the maximum. Could some one maybe suggest any (utility) functions that have 3 (also 4) variables (doesn't matter if it has constants).
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say you have $k$ goods $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k$. Let $\mathbf{x}$ denote the vector $\mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ \ldots \\  x_k \end{bmatrix}$.

#### Some common workhorses to get you started:

- [Multivariate Cobb-Douglas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobb%E2%80%93Douglas_production_function): $u(\mathbf{x}) = \prod_{i=1}^k x_i^{\lambda_i} $.

  - Note that $\max_\mathbf{x} u(\mathbf{x})$ has the same solution as $\max_\mathbf{x} \log u(\mathbf{x})$ because the logarithm is a monotonically increasing function. Hence maximizing the utility function $u(\mathbf{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i \log x_i$ will give the same solution and also is referred to as Cobb-Douglas.
- [Constant elasticity of substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_elasticity_of_substitution) $u(\mathbf{x}) = \left( \sum_i \alpha_i ^\frac{1}{s} x_i ^\frac{s - 1}{s}\right)^\frac{s}{s-1}$

Answer (score 1):

To get started note that there are three main types of utility functions/production functions in economics. for a multi-variable case I'll illustrate it below.

**Complements**
$$U(\mathbf{X})=\min\{x_i,...,x_n\}$$
**Subsitutes**
$$U(\mathbf{X)}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_1x_i$$

where $a_i$ is a constant greater than zero (for normal goods).

**Cobb-douglas** (as Matthew Gunn has already said).
$$u(\mathbf{X}) = \prod_i^n x_i^{\lambda_i} $$

where each $\lambda_i$ is greater than zero (for normal goods).

Hope this helps.

Comment: The complements and substitutes forms might not work too well if the essay is using Lagrangian maximisation.

Comment: @Ubiquitous agreed. still its a useful reference.

Answer (score 1):

The word "utility" is in brackets in the body of your question, so I am not sure if it means that you prefer or that you only want utility maximization problems. Anyway, here is an optimization problem that is not about utility.

Suppose a company produces output $y$ using inputs $x_1$ and $x_2$. The technology used is described by the concave production function $f(x_1,x_2)$. (For example $\sqrt{x_1x_2}$.) The company wishes to minimize its costs, that is given the input prices $w_1$ and $w_2$ it wishes to produce $y$ units as cheaply as possible.

The optimization problem is
\begin{align*}
\min_{x_1,x_2} \ & w_1x_1 + w_2x_2 \\
\\
\mbox{s.t. } & f(x_1,x_2) = y \\
\\
& x_1,x_2 \geq 0.
\end{align*}
Assuming the solution is an interior solution, that is $x_1^*, x_2^* > 0$, the Lagrange-multiplier of the production function's condition has a rather nice economic meaning. It is the marginal cost of production.

If you insist on three or more variables, you can easily adjust the number of inputs, e.g. $f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = \sqrt[4]{x_1x_2x_3}$.

Comment: +1 Understanding the typical utility maximization problem subject to a budget constraint is nice, but understanding more broadly the mathematics of optimization is better! Optimization is fantastically useful and shows up *everywhere.*